# If $F^n(b_n x) \to e^{-x^{-\alpha}}$, $b_n x \to x_0$ where $x_0 = \sup \{x \colon F(x) < 1 \}$

Tags: distributions, convergence, extreme-value

Let $X_n$ be i.i.d with common df $F$. Let $M_n = \max (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$. Suppose $P(b_n^{-1} M_n \leq x) = F^n(b_n x) \to e^{-x^{-\alpha}}$ weakly, where $x > 0$ and $\alpha > 0$.

Let $x_0 = \sup \{x \colon F(x) < 1 \}$. I want to prove that $x_0 = \infty$, and my book says that if $x_0 < \infty$, then for $x>0$, we must have $b_n x \to x_0$. However, I'm not sure why this follows. If someone could explain that step, I'd be grateful.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What is this book?  By the way, can you change all of the $a_n$s in your typing to $b_n$ so that they are consistent with the screenshot you took?

Comment: @Zhanxiong Extreme Values, Regular Variation, and Point Process or Heavy-Tail Phenomena by Resnick(the two books have the same first chapter).

Comment: Take any number $0\lt q\le 1.$ What happens to $q^{1/n}$ as $n\to\infty$? Apply this to $q=\Phi_\alpha(x).$

Comment: @whuber Since $F^n(b_n x) \to \Phi(x)$, $F(b_n x) \sim \Phi^{\frac{1}{n}}(x)$($a_n \sim b_n$ if $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to 1$), but $[\Phi_\alpha(x)]^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 0$, so $F(b_n x) \to 0$ as well? That doesn't seem right since if $b_n x \to x_0$, $F(b_n x)$ wouldn't converge to $0$.

Comment: Re "but ...": *are you sure?*

Comment: @whuber I see I read that wrong, $\Phi^{\frac{1}{n}}(x) \to 1$, so $F(b_n x) \to 1$ as well, so $b_n x \to x_0$ otherwise $F(b_n x)$ doesn't converge to $1$, just have to make it more rigorous since we don't have continuity at $x_0$ but this seems like the right idea.

Comment: Your question is good, I feel this proof is not solid and quite hard to make a quick fix.

Comment: @Zhanxiong yeah I'll have to think about it too

Comment: This *might* be relevant:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341281/normalising-constant-of-the-gumbel-in-extreme-value-theory#:~:text=If%20there%20exists%20%7B%20a%20n%20%7D%20n,n%29%20and%20a%20n%20%E2%89%A1%20A%20%28b%20n%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim "*we get from (2.9) that for $x > 0$, $b_nx \to x_0$*" definitely requires some elaboration, to which I don't find an easy way to fix. However, to show the ultimate goal $x_0 = \infty$, the italicized statement can be bypassed by showing under the assumption $x_0 < \infty$ it follows that

1. $b_n \to 0$.
2. $x_0 \leq 0$.

Hence the contradiction can be derived as the last statement in the screenshot.

If $x_0 < \infty$, then for all $x > x_0$, $F(x) = 1$. Then if $\limsup_n b_n > 0$, there would exist a subsequence $\{b_{n_k}\}$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty}b_{n_k} = b > 0$, whence there would be some positive $x^*$ such that $b_{n_k}x^* > x_0$ for all $k$, which implies that $F^{n_k}(b_{n_k}x^*) \equiv 1 \not\to \Phi_\alpha(x^*)$ as $k \to \infty$.  Therefore, $(2.9)$ and $x_0 < \infty$ must imply $b_n \to 0$.

On the other hand, for fixed $x > 0$, by the inequality (cf. Theorem 3.37 in
*Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (3rd ed.) by Walter Rudin)
\begin{align}
\liminf_n \frac{F^{n + 1}(b_{n + 1}x)}{F^n(b_nx)} \leq \liminf_n F(b_nx) \leq 
\limsup_n F(b_nx) \leq \limsup_n \frac{F^{n + 1}(b_{n + 1}x)}{F^n(b_nx)}
\end{align}
and $(2.9)$, it follows that $F(b_nx) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. The right-continuity of $F$ and $b_n \to 0$ then imply $F(0) = 1$. Hence $x_0$ must be less than or equal to $0$. This completes the proof of 2 and the result follows.