# distribution for scaled Maximum of n independent Weibulls for $n \to \infty$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, asymptotics, weibull-distribution, extreme-value

Assume that $X_1, X_2,...\sim Weibull(\lambda, k) \quad iid.$, i.e.

$F(X_1\leq x) = 1-e^{-(\lambda x)^k}$

define $M_n:= \max\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ and $\tilde{M}_n:=\frac{M_n-b_n}{a_n}$

according to extreme value theory the distribution of $\tilde{M}_n$ approaches for a proper choice of $a_n,b_n$ a distribution function:

$$G(x)= \exp\left\{-\left[1+\xi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]^{-1/\xi}\right\}$$.

where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma>0, \xi \in \mathbb{R}$ the case $\xi=0$ is interpreted as $\xi \to 0$

I.e.: $$\left\{1-\exp\left[-\lambda^k \left(\frac{x-b_n}{a_n}\right)^k\right]\right\}^n\to G(z), \quad n \to \infty$$

the expression on the left side can be reformulated as :

$$\left\{1-\exp\left[-\lambda^k \left(\frac{x-b_n}{a_n}\right)^k\right]\right\}^n=\left\{1- \frac{n\exp\left[-\lambda^k \left(\frac{x-b_n}{a_n}\right)^k\right]}{n}\right\}^n$$

so I need to find sequences $a_n,b_n$, such that

$$n\exp\left[-\lambda^k \left(\frac{x-b_n}{a_n}\right)^k\right]\to \left[1+\xi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]^{-1/\xi}, n \to \infty$$

I would be glad if you could help me finding these sequences.

Comment: The definition of $M_n$ is $M_n := \max\{X_1,\, X_2, \dots, \,
X_n\}$. Also note that $\text{Pr}\{\tilde{M}_n \leqslant x \} =
F_X^n(a_n x + b_n)$.  If you want to find the (some) constants by
yourself, you may use my former answer
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/285991/10479). Suitable
constants are available e.g. in the [famous book by Embrechts et
al](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540609315); see table 3.4.4
the "Weibull-like" case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determination of the domain of attraction and of the related
constants $a_n$ and $b_n$ uses several functions related to the survival
function, here given by $S(x) = \exp\{-(\lambda x)^k\}$ for $x > 0$.
Of major importance are the *tail-quantile* function $U(t)$ and the
*hazard rate* function $h(x)$.

The tail-quantile is obtained by solving $S(U) = 1/t$ for $U$, which
leads to $U(t) = \lambda^{-1} (\log t)^{1/k}$ for $t> 1$. The hazard
rate is $h(x) = -\text{d}\log S(x)/\text{d}x = \lambda^k \, k
\,x^{k-1}$ for $x>0$.  The derivative of the inverse hazard rate
$1/h(x)$ is proportional to $x^{-k}$, hence tends to zero for large
$x$ since $k>0$. So the *Von Mises' condition* holds.  We know that
the distribution is in the Gumbel domain of attraction and that we
have the following convergence in distribution to the standard Gumbel

\begin{equation}
\frac{M_n - U(n)}{a_n} \to \text{Gumbel}.
\end{equation}

Moreover we know that we can choose $a_n$ as $e(U(n))$ where $e(x)$
denotes the *mean residual life* function given by $e(x) := A(x) /
S(x)$ with $A(x) := \int_{x}^\infty S(t) \,\text{d}t$ for $x >0$.

We now proceed to the evaluation of $e(U(n))$ or to the
determination of a quantity which is equivalent to it for large
$n$. Using the change of variable $u := (\lambda t)^k$ we get

$$
  A(x) = \int_{x}^\infty \exp\{-(\lambda t)^k\}\,\text{d}t= \frac{1}{\lambda k}
  \int_{(\lambda x)^k}^{\infty} u^{1/k -1} e^{-u} \text{d}u 
    = (\lambda k)^{-1} \, \Gamma(s,\, v),
$$

where $\Gamma(s,\,v)$ stands for the [incomplete gamma
function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)
evaluated at $s:= 1/k$ and $v := (\lambda x)^k$. We can use the
following known result about the incomplete gamma $\Gamma(s,\, v) \sim
v^{s-1} e^{-v}$ for $v \to \infty$ which can be shown using
integration by parts. So

$$
e(x) \sim 
\frac{(\lambda k)^{-1}\, \left\{ (\lambda x)^k  \right\}^{1/k - 1}
\exp\{- (\lambda x)^k \}}{S(x)} = \frac{x}{k} \, (\lambda x)^{-k}.
$$

Note that $h(x) \times e(x)$ tends to $1$ for large $x$, which is
clear from the last equivalence; this limit condition is both
necessary an sufficient for the attraction to the Gumbel when $h(x)$
is monotonic for large $x$, as is the case here - see Theorem 1 in
[Galambos and
Obretenov](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414987902043).
We can choose $a_n$ as $1 / h(U(n))$, and our constants can
be

$$
    a_n = \dfrac{1}{\lambda k} \, (\log n)^{1/k -1}, \qquad
    b_n = \dfrac{1}{\lambda} \, (\log n )^{1/k}.
$$

A precise statement of Von Mises' condition is found in the classical
book [*Modelling Extremal Events*](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540609315) by Embrechts
P., Klüppelberg C. and Mikosch T. In this book (up to change in
notations), the couple of constants is given in Table 3.4.4.

```
## Weibull parameters
k <- 2.5; lambda <- 10
## simulate
set.seed(123)
n <- 40; nsim <- 10000
X <- array(rweibull(n * nsim, shape = k, scale = 1/ lambda), dim = c(nsim, n))
M <- apply(X, 1, max)
bn <- log(n)^(1 / k) / lambda
an <- log(n)^(1 / k - 1) / lambda / k
Mscale <- scale(M, center = bn, scale = an)
hist(Mscale, breaks = 100, probability = TRUE, col = "lightyellow",
     main = sprintf("Simulated maxima for n = %d", n), xlab = "")
require(evd)
curve(dgumbel, add = TRUE, col = "orangered", lwd  = 2)
```

[image]