# Convergence rate of the maximum of Weibull random variables to a Gumbel distribution

Tags: r, convergence, weibull-distribution, extreme-value, gumbel-distribution

Given a sequence of iid samples $X_1, \dots, X_n,$ where each $X_i$ comes from a Weibull distribution with shape parameter $k$ and scale parameter $\lambda$. Then it is a well-known result that the maximum $M_n:=max(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ converges weakly to a Gumbel distribution.

I am wondering: How large should $n$ be in practice such that $M_n$ can be fitted reasonably by a Gumbel distribution?

The reason why I ask the question is as follows. I performed some simulation studies in `R`, where I simulated Weibull distributed samples for different sample sizes, shape and scale parameters and then I fitted a Gumbel distribution to the resulting maxima. I plotted the histogram of the maxima and plotted the estimated Gumbel density to compare both.
Consider the following example code:

```
library("fitdistrplus")
library("extraDistr")
k <- 1
lambda <- 1
n_sim <- 1e5
n <- 1e4
m <- numeric(n_sim)
for (i in 1:n_sim) {
    m[i] <- max(rweibull(n, shape = k, scale = lambda))
}
gumbel_fit <- fitdist(m, "gumbel", start = list("mu" = 0, "sigma" = 1))$estimate
m_hist <- hist(m, breaks = 50, freq = F)
x_seq <- seq(min(m_hist$breaks), max(m_hist$breaks), , 1000)
y <- dgumbel(x_seq, mu = gumbel_fit[1], sigma = gumbel_fit[2])
lines(x_seq, y, col = "red")
```

Taking $k=1, \lambda = 1, n=10^4,$ and $n_{sim}=10^5$ gives the following plot.[image]

In this case we see an almost perfect fit.

Now change the shape parameter to $k=0.3$ and keep all other parameters. This results in the following.[image]

For this scale parameter the Gumbel distribution yields no sufficient approximation. In particular the bad approximation of the right tail is troublesome, as I am mainly interested in big quantiles of the estimated distribution. Fitting a Generalized Extreme Value distribution yields much better approximations.

Now let $k=3$ and keep all other parameters. This yields the following plot.
[image]

Again, it seems that the Gumbel distribution cannot fit the data, which can be seen nicely in the tails.

To conclude: Although the Weibull distribution belongs to the maximum domain of attraction of the Gumbel distribution, the goodness of fit of a Gumbel distribution depends heavily on the parameters and for some combinations of scale and shape parameter it seems to take a ridiculous sample size $n$ that $M_n$ can be fitted reasonably by a Gumbel distribution.

Are my conclusions correct? How can you estimate the sample size $n$ that it takes for a reasonable fit? Is it advisable in practice to use the Gumbel distribution or should one always fit a Generalized Extreme Value distribution to the data?

Comment: Welcome to CV. The well-known convergence result is for $[M_n -
b_n]/a_n$ where the two sequences $a_n>0$ and $b_n$ matter. The
determination of these sequences is quite technical, but usable
sequences can be found in the classical references on Extreme-Value
Theory, see my answer to [this
question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/394682/10479). Yet I never
heard about an analogue of the Berry-Esseen bound for the
Fisher-Tippett-Gnedenko theorem...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yeah, I looked up the results on the sequences just today in the book by Embrechts, Klüppelberg and Mikosch but I don't know how to translate them into some kind of convergence rate. If $k=1$, the sequence $a_n$ is independent of $n$, when I remenber it correctly at the moment. Hence, the convergence in this case is really good. But if $k\neq 1$, the convergence rate seems to be very slow.

Comment: My comment (by mistake, I first  I pasted it in an answer, deleted) tells that the convergence does not hold if you ignore $a_n$ and $b_n$. But as you noticed, the convergence is faster when $k \approx 1$ the tail being then nearly Gumbel. I can not answer to your question: you ask for a bound on $|F_{M_n}(x) - F_{\text{Gum}}(x)|$

Comment: Yes, such an bound would very interesting. However, until now I found some results for the normal distribution: [Peter Hall](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3212912.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A10f86d503642a76da45cce8985970798) showed that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|F_{M_n}(x) - F_{Gum}(x)|$ converges to zero with $log(n)$ and that this is the best you can get. I fear you won't get a better result for Weibull random variables. This implies for the practice that you may need insanely large sample sizes to trust the approximation in the tails, I fear.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting neat result. Some classical books contain
parts about convergence rates: sections 3.3, 3.4 of [Beirlant et
al](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0470012382),
chap. 4 of [de Haan and
Ferreira](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387239460). In both
cases, some math is still needed to find the bound:)