# What is the distribution of a bivariate normal component conditional on the max of the other component?

Tags: normal-distribution, model-selection, order-statistics, extreme-value

Let $n$ be a large integer, and consider two independent multivariate Gaussian $n$-vectors $x, z$ with $x\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,I\right),$ and $z\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2 I\right)$. Let $y=x+z$. Conditional on observing $y$, consider the reindexing $(i)$ such that $y_{(1)} \le y_{(2)} \le \cdots \le y_{(n-1)} \le y_{(n)}$. What can we say about $x_{(n)}$?

1. Do we know the conditional distribution of $x_{(n)}$?
2. Failing that, can we compute or estimate the conditional expected value of $x_{(n)}$?
3. In each of these, what are the asymptotics of $x_{(n)}$ as $n\to \infty$?

*background*: this is like an estimation after selection procedure where the $x$ are some unobserved population parameter that you observe with noise $z$, and the indices are over different 'models'. You select the model with the largest estimated parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$Y_{(n)}$ is the largest of $n$ points drawn from a bivariate Normal distribution.  Its $X$ coordinate is more or less likely to be an extreme value among the corresponding $X$ coordinates provided $X$ and $Y$ are strongly correlated.  Even then, the variability in $X$ limits the degree to which this can happen: a manifestation of the *regression to the mean* phenomenon.

[image: Figure showing a realization with n=128]

*This scatterplot of a sample of size $n=128$ highlights the point with largest $Y$ value, $Y_{(n)}.$ The colored lines show the coordinates.  Note that its x-coordinate, corresponding to the position of the vertical blue line, is not the largest among the x coordinates.  Regression theory explains that this x coordinate $X_{(n)}$ will vary in a Normal fashion from the value predicted from $Y_{(n)}.$*  (Note the reversal in the usual roles of $X$ and $Y:$ the setup of the question requires us to predict $X$ from $Y$ rather than the other way around.)

---

The conditions given in the question imply $(X,Y)$ has a bivariate Normal distribution.  Its correlation coefficient is

$$\rho = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}{Y}}} = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X,X+Z)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(X+
Z)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1)(1+\sigma^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\sigma^2}}.$$

We may analyze all bivariate Normal distributions at once, recognizing that suitable choices of units for $X$ and $Y$ reduce it to the condition where $X$ and $Y$ are standard Normal with correlation $\rho.$  (In particular, $X$ is already standard Normal and so needs no standardization at all.)

Let $\Phi$ be the standard Normal CDF.  Following the analyses at [Extreme Value Theory - Show: Normal to Gumbel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105745), the CDF of the maximum of $n$ iid observations $Y_{(n)}$ is $\Phi^n$ which, for large $n$, can be standardized to approximate a Gumbel distribution.  At the same time, the theory of linear regression establishes that the distribution of $X$ is that of $\rho Y + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\,\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ has a standard Normal distribution (independent of $(X,Y)$).  Therefore

> $X$ is distributed as the linear combination of independent variables with $\Phi^n$ and $\Phi$ distribution functions.  The coefficients are $\rho$ and $\sqrt{1-\rho^2},$ respectively.

Asymptotically, an appropriately scaled version of $Y$ has a Gumbel distribution (*id.*).  The scaling factor decreases to zero in the limit.  One asymptotic expression for the location factor is

$$\mu(n) = \Phi^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Therefore

> Asymptotically, $(X - \rho\mu(n))/\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$ has a standard Normal distribution.

---

The following figures present simulation results that check and illustrate these conclusions.  "$n$" is the sample size.  A correlation coefficient of $\rho=0.8$ was used.  Each of the four (independent) simulations obtained $100,000$ independent realizations of $(X_{(n)}, Y_{(n)}).$  The upper plots are histograms of the realized values of $Y_{(n)}$ and the lower plots are the corresponding histograms of the realized values of $X_{(n)}.$  The overplotted colored curves are the asymptotic Gumbel (red, top) and Normal (blue, bottom) distributions, scaled to fit the data.

[image: Figure]

It is evident that (a) the Gumbel approximation is good by the time $n=100$ and (b) although the convergence of $X$ to a normal variable is slow, by the time $n=10^{25}$ the difference is undetectable.

---

The `R` code that produced these results runs almost instantaneously--demonstrating the relative simplicity of all the calculations--and is provided for further experimentation.

```R
#
# Generate random variates far into the upper tail of the standard Normal
# distribution (Mills' Ratio approximation).
#
qnorm.0 <- function(log.q) {
  f <- function(x) sqrt(-2*log(-sqrt(2*pi) * x * log.q))
  ifelse(log.q < -1e-12, qnorm(exp(log.q)), f(f(f(7))))
  # obj <- uniroot(function(x) sqrt(2*pi) * x * log.q + exp(-x^2/2), c(lower, upper))
  # obj$root
}
#
# Gumbel PDF.
#
dGumbel <- function(x, mu=0, sigma=1) {z <- (x-mu)/sigma; exp(-z - exp(-z))/sigma}
#
# Standardization of Normal maximum distribution for largish n.
#
snorm <- function(n) {
  c(mu = qnorm.0(-1/n), sigma = 1 / sqrt(2*log(n) - log(2*pi))) 
}
#
# Run the simulations, plotting as we go.
#
rho <- 0.8
N <- 1e5          # Simulation size
set.seed(17)      # For reproducibility
par(mfcol=c(2,4))
for (n in 10^c(1, 2, 5, 25)) {
  # Generate and display Y
  y <- qnorm.0(-rexp(N, n))
  hist(y, main=paste("n =", n), breaks=30, freq=FALSE, 
       xlab=expression(y[(n)]), cex.lab=1.25)
  ab <- snorm(n)
  curve(dGumbel(x, ab[1], ab[2]), add=TRUE, col="#e02020", lwd=2)

  # Generate and display X
  x <- rho * y + sqrt(1-rho^2) * rnorm(N, 0, 1)
  tau <- sqrt(1-rho^2)
  hist(x, breaks=30, freq=FALSE, ylim=c(0, sqrt(1/(2*pi)) / tau), 
       xlab=expression(x[(n)]), cex.lab=1.25)
  curve(dnorm(x, rho*ab[1], tau), add=TRUE, col="#2020e0", lwd=2)
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
# #
# # Check the fast method (above) by comparison to the straightforward one.
# # The QQ plot lies close to the X=X.1 line, demonstrating equivalence.
# #
# library(MASS)
# n <- 1000
# N <- 1e4
# xy <- aperm(array(mvrnorm(n*N, c(0,0), matrix(c(1,rho,rho,1), 2)), c(N,n,2)), c(2,3,1))
# 
# x <- apply(xy, 3, function(xy) {
#   i <- which.max(xy[, 2])
#   xy[i, 1]
# })
# # hist(x, main=paste0("n =", n))
# 
# x.1 <- rho * qnorm(runif(N)^(1/n)) + sqrt(1-rho^2) * rnorm(N, 0, sigma)
# plot(sort(x), sort(x.1), main="q-q plot", xlab="Direct", ylab="Shortcut")
# abline(c(0,1), col="Red", lwd=2)
```

Comment: This is really great. I had thought to approach the problem with Stein's Lemma, but have not made much headway.

Comment: Is it possible that the law should be $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\rho^2 \mu(n), 1-\rho^2\right)$?

Comment: @shabby I don't think so.  For some concrete evidencel, note that the plots for $n=10^{25}$ contradict that.

Comment: @whuber see my answer below, though I suspect I have mixed up the relationship between conditional on $y$ observed and the mean value of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

My comment to @whuber is based on the following reasoning:
Suppose that $x \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2\right)$,
and $y \left| x \right. \sim \mathcal{N}\left(x,\sigma_y^2\right)$.
Then the stacked vector of $x, y$ is bivariate normal:
$$
\left[x, y\right]^{\top} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\left[\mu_x, \mu_x\right]^{\top}, 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_x^2 & \sigma_x^2\\
\sigma_x^2 & \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2
\end{array}\right]
\right).
$$

By the [conditional normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions), 
conditional on $y=a$ for some $a$, $x$ is normal
$$
x \left| \left\{ y = a \right\} \right. \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_x +
\frac{\sigma_x}{\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}} \rho \left(a - \mu_x\right),
\left(1-\rho^2\right)\sigma_x^2\right),
$$
where $\rho$ is the correlation of $x$ and $y$, which takes value
$$
\rho = \frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_x \sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}} 
= \frac{\sigma_x}{\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}}.
$$
Thus
$$
x \left| \left\{ y = a \right\} \right. \sim
\mathcal{N}\left(\left(1-\rho^2\right) \mu_x + \rho^2 a,
\left(1-\rho^2\right)\sigma_x^2\right).
$$
Substituting in $\mu_x=0$ and $\sigma_x=1$ gives the desired relation.

Comment: It's difficult to see how this answers the question: where is the consideration of the order statistics?