# Precision issues using truncnorm in R

Tags: truncated-normal-distribution, truncated-distributions

I'm facing some precision issues with **truncnorm**, particularly the **ptruncnorm()** function in R. Here's an example where I find the cdf up to $q= 2$, where the truncation point is $1.9$, for several truncated normal distributions that differ only in the means of the distribution.

```
mean_grid <- seq(-7,0, 0.01)

cdf_list <- c()

for (mean_val in mean_grid) {
  cdf <- ptruncnorm(q = 2, a =1.90, b = Inf, mean = mean_val, sd = 1)
  cdf_list <- c(cdf_list, cdf)
}


plot(x = mean_grid, y = cdf_list, xlab = "truncnorm mean", ylab=  "cdf (X <= 2)")
```

For mean values (x-axis) at the very left the cdf returns NaN which is reasonable. What I don't understand is that before that, the y-values become haphazard and lose the monotonic pattern in the rest of the graph.

This affects me because I actually want to solve a form: given the truncation point $t$ and a quintile $q$, and an area $c$, solve for a mean $\mu$ such that $\Phi_{t,\mu}(q) = c$, where $\Phi_{t,\mu}$ is the truncated normal cdf. And I use **uniroot()** to solve this numerically, but if the truncated cdf is not accurate in a region like this then I can't trust the solution.

Does anyone know why this volatility occurs? Am I correct that this is computational precision issue - and if so is there a way to find a more accurate truncated normal cdf?

[image: plots of cdf]

Comment: Since `ptruncnorm` is not a standard part of `R`, please explain what its arguments mean and what it is supposed to return.  The code for `qnorm.0` I posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/416791/919 shows how to implement the standard Normal quantile function far out into the upper tail--you might find that helpful.  It's even easier to implement `pnorm` far into the tail: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7206/919.  Also see the related analysis of truncated Normal means at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/166277/919.

Comment: Thank you @whuber. `ptruncnorm()` is from the `truncnorm` package, and you identified the crux of the issue: poor definition/behavior in the tails. Looking into this further I saw that the package `TruncatedNormal` behaves much better in the tails, and it will suffice for my purposes.