# Normalization of $M_{n} = \max(U_{1}, ... , U_{n})$

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, extreme-value

Let $M_{n}  = \max(U_{1}... , U_{n})$ be the maximum of a sample size $n$ from $U(0 , 1)$ distribution.

In my statistics textbook it says that $M_{n}$ normalized is equal to $n(1 - M_{n})$ but I'm not sure how they got to this?

I know that any order statistic derived from a $U(0 , 1)$ distribution follows a Beta distribution, but I'm not sure if this will help me get to the answer.

Comment: What does 'Normalization of $M_n$' mean? Have you left out any details?

Comment: I think it means subtracting by the mean and dividing by the standard deviation.

Comment: Do you know which Beta distribution corresponds to that of $M_n$?  If so, what is its mean and standard deviation?

Comment: $n(1-M_n)$ is an appropriate norming and scaling of $M_n$ so that it converges to a standard (non-degenerate) distribution. Maybe that is the context which you do not mention.

Comment: "Normalized" likely means in the sense of the FTG theorem, as I explain at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/153067/919.  The techniques shown there apply to the present situation (and the analysis is much simpler).