Rough answer for the maximum of absolute value of $n$ standard gaussians (Computer Age Statistical Inference Problem 1.3)
I am working through "Computer Age Statistical Inference" as a self-study and am stuck on the follow exercise (1.3):

The details of equation 1.6 are unimportant for the exercise, so far as I can tell this question boils down to

what is the expected maximum absolute value of 7128 samples from $T(70)$?

Since $T(70) \approx N(0,1)$ I think the first step is to view this as equivalent to the question

what is the expected maximum absolute value of 7128 samples from $N(0,1)$?

I have seen that there are several exact bounds which can be derived (e.g. here , here, and here), but the math involved is rather intense and seems far from the intended solution given the hint.
Would someone be able to help give me a step in the right direction for how I can compute an approximate solution and make use of the hint in the problem?
I am very grateful for your help :)
P.S. computationally, it seems like the answer is about 3.76 or so.

Hint:  What is the $1-1/7128$th percentile of a standard Normal distribution?  Of a $t(70) $ distribution?

Another note is that since we will be really far out in the tails of the distribution (that's another hint), the Student-t distribution with 70 degrees of freedom isn't that well approximated by a standard normal

It seems that this is pointing in the direction of the classic "you can expect a 5% event to happen once every 20 trials" argument...
If I were to do that I would compute $F_{T(70)}^{-1}(1 - 0.5 * 1/7128) \approx 4.02$ which basically says "I can expect to see a T statistic $\geq 4.02$ once across my 7128 samples.
Is that essentially the extent of the argument? There is obviously a lot of fuzziness there (if we were to compute say a chernoff bound on the event count we would see we can't say it is 1 with high probability), but perhaps this is the nature of a heuristic argument.

Re "heuristic:" yes, but it can be made rigorous. I explain and illustrate the underlying concept (using the Normal distribution) in detail at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/153067/919.  It all applies to Student t distributions, too.

Thanks to all the helpful comments. For others who are stuck, consider the following as a stronger hint: "if you sample Bernoulli(0.05) 20 times, you can expect to see it come up as 1 once." For more details please see the comments. It seems possible to formalize the intuition through the arguments whuber made here
